# $f$ is continuous in $a$ iff every convergent sequence with limit $a$, $f(x_n)$ converges to$ f(a)$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Can someone please check the first part of my proof and help me with the second part? I know similar questions haven been posted here in the past, but the answers did not help me out.

Let $f: V \rightarrow W$ be a map between metric spaces.

Prove: $f$ is continuous in $a \in V$ if and only if for every convergent sequence $(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $V$ with limit $a$ the sequence $(f(x_{n}))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $W$ is convergent with limit $f(a)$.

Attempted proof:

$\Rightarrow$ We know that:

1) For every $\epsilon_{1} > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $d(x_{n}, a) < \delta \Rightarrow d(f(x_{n}), f(a)) < \epsilon_{1}$.

2) For every $\epsilon_{2} > 0$ there exists a $N_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N_{1} \Rightarrow d(x_{n}, a) < \epsilon_{2}$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose $\epsilon_{1} = \epsilon$. Then there exists a $\delta$ such that $$d(x_{n}, a) < \delta \Rightarrow d(f(x_{n}), f(a)) < \epsilon$$

Now choose $\epsilon_{2} = \delta$. Then there exists a $N_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$n > N_{1} \Rightarrow d(x_{n}, a) < \delta$$

Now, let $N = N_{1}$. Then $n > N \Rightarrow d(x_{n}, a) < \delta \Rightarrow d(f(x_{n}), f(a)) < \epsilon$. So, $(f(x_{n}))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $W$ is convergent with limit $f(a)$.

$\Leftarrow$ Could not figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for the first part is correct.
Now for the second part, maybe work with a proof by contradiction?
Suppose there is a $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $\delta >0$ there exists an $x \in V$ such that $d(x,a) < \delta$ and $d(f(x),f(a) > \epsilon$. Now if you take for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ a $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$, you can construct a sequence $x_n \to a$ but $f(x_n) \not \to f(a)$.